# How to get a file dependencies in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example

file a:

```
var b=require('b.js');
var c=require('c.js');
```

file b:

```
var d=require('d.js');
```

I want to list the dependencies of a.js and result is b.js and d.js;
I try https://github.com/pahen/madge, it works, but too slow.